# print photo from javascript

Tags: javascript, php, json

I am retrieving same data with photos from a database with a query in PHP. i am sending this photos to Javascript as json. i get the encoded json string in javascript and i parse it
`data = JSON.parse(request.responseText);` 
now i am printing the data in html. everything works okay. Except photos.
This is how i print data and photos:

```
tab.innerHTML += "<p>"+data[h].product_name+"</p>";
tab.innerHTML += "<p><img src="+data[h].product_photo+" alt='sorry no image'></p>";
```

I get this error

```
Not allowed to load local resource: file:///E:/xampp
localhost/:1 GET http://localhost/images/ 404 (Not Found)
alt='sorry:1 GET http://localhost/gamo9/css3_tabbed_nav/alt='sorry 404 (Not Found)
null:1 GET http://localhost/gamo9/css3_tabbed_nav/null 404 (Not Found)
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

What does data[h].product_photo have?

It should either be an URL of image loaded somewhere.
Or it can be base64 encoded image that you can display using something like:

`src="data:image/png;base64,...........

Comment: its a URL :       E:xampp mpphpD58F.tmp

Comment: If mpphpD58F.tmp is what it is coming out then it is only filename. You need to add something like hxxp://example.com/.... to make it load from that server. For example if your server is localhost and image is being hosted on default path then your code should look like: <img src=hxxp://localhost/xampp/"+data[h].product_photo+" alt='sorry no image'>

(Replease hxxp with http)